# How to execute a stored procedure in Apache Delta Spike

Tags: java, jpa, deltaspike, deltaspike-jpa

I'm using Apache Delta Spike's Data module in my project, however, I don't find in it's documentation a proper way to execute and get results from a stored procedure call...

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

sorry, a bit late, but it should work like this, e.g. when you do a native SQL call (I use DB2 and have one parameter coming back from the call of the procedure):

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "call YOURSCHEMANAME.SP_YOURPROCNAME(:outParam)", isNative = true)
public abstract Integer yourMethodName(@QueryParam("outParam") Integer outParam);
```